# Stopping 100+ Message Boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping through files and to test I made a message box appear with each file name. This worked until I tested a folder with over a hundred files in it, and now it looks like I need to click "OK" one hundred times. I'm looking for a way out of this mistake for future uses.

Say I had this code for example:

```
Sub no_escape()
    Dim i as Integer
    For i = 0 to 101
        Msgbox i
    Next i
End sub
```

**Is there any way to stop these message boxes from appearing, after the program has started, without closing excel?**

I am not able to select the vba code as the message box prompts me to click it first, but as soon as I do another message box appears.

Comment: You can try to do a Ctrl+Break or just hold down the enter key until you get through all the message boxes. 100 isn't too many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to stop the message boxes without closing your excel instance is to simply hold the `ESC` key.
As for preventing them from appearing, it does not look like that is possible once they have started going.